# What is wrong with my PSP's thumbstick to make a character walk the opposite direction

Tags: hardware, psp

Recently i've been noticing that when i push up in the thumb stick my character actually moves down, i've mainly been noticing this in Disgaea in the overloads castle where using the thumbstick is preferred for movement there

Now at first i thought that maybe the stick was wearing out cause it's a first gen PSP and i've never swapped it (the second one i got was for the purpose to play on the TVT, not a replacement) but thinking back evidence of that would be the character automatically moving up because i used to play a lot of Dissidia Final Fantasy

So i'm wondering what could be wrong with my thumb stick that it would make a character move down when i press up, what actually happens is that Lahal moves up but then stops and starts switching his facing front front to back and start slightly move downwards, if i move the stick slightly to the right he moves strait down and because of the thumb stick i can't down exactly the position of the stick

Comment: Is this happening only in Disgaea?  Or does it happen in other games?  That will determine whether it's a game setting, or your PSP.

Comment: @fbueckert it happens in Shin Megami Tensei: Persona but i rarely use the thumb stick in it, sometimes in menus the cursor would keep moving down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be an issue with calibration. Sometimes the stick sets the center of its movement range to somewhere other than the center due to getting worn out.

Try going to the Settings area of the PSP's main menu, then down to System Settings section, then to the System Information section, and on that screen, try rotating the stick along the very edge of it's available area a few times, and see if that helps .

Comment: Then the symptoms would be walking when the stick isn't being touched. Miscalibration wouldn't reverse the axis.

Comment: True. Rereading the question, I realized that I had misunderstood what Memor-X meant with the "slightly moving downwards." However, calibrating couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @WingManEXE your initial answer is what i originally thought, i'll try the recalibration thing when i get home from work

Comment: @WingManEXE wow, i can not believe that did something, when i started up disgaea i was almost fixed, the symptom did occur for a brief moment but i haven't came across it since, though this is probably only a band aid solution, is the system menu option also a calibration tester as well?

Comment: @Memor-X How do you mean calibration tester? Like, are you asking if it will tell you if it's calibrated? Because sadly it can't do that. However, once it's been recalibrated, the PSP usually remembers the new calibration settings for a while. I had to recalibrate mine about 5-6 months ago, and it's still good.

Comment: @WingManEXE by Calibration Tester i'm talking about something like the touch screen Calibration Tester you get at the end of the calibration settings on the Nintendo DS

Comment: Ah, I see. Sadly, it's not, since the control stick isn't compatible with the PSP's main menu for some silly reason. Most games use it however, so I've just gone to a game to see if it worked.